# What UK 80s TV kids show had a ghost in a hat and coat looking for treasure?

Tags: story-identification, tv, ghost

Does anyone recognise this ITV children's show from the 80's?

It was in-part a ghost story, which involved a ghost looking for treasure he had hidden in a house. At one point he causes a car to crash by stepping in front of it with his arms outstretched. I remember the ghost having a large hat and a long coat. It could have been from something like Dramarama. I would love to know what it was.

Comment: Hmm. Edit button is missing on mobile. Weird.

Comment: @Valorum Edit is there for me on mobile.

Comment: @bellerophon - It's back now. How odd.

Comment: Cartoon or live action?

Comment: Parts of this remind me of *Ghost Dad*...

Comment: @FuzzyBoots: Dramarama was always live action, so presumably not a cartoon.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is **Flying Phantom Ship (1969)** ([IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0065021/)). I definitely can recall a situation with a car crash and some ghost in the coat.

Comment: I'm sure it was newer than that.  Think early 80s.   Have never come across it again though.

Comment: Sounds like a good guess, I don’t think we got a lot of Japanese animation on UK kids TV in the 80s.